# Data Types on the fly

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, theory

Is it possible to dynamically declare arrays or variables after compilation? I ask because it is the only way I can think to solve this problem I've been running in to.

What I am trying to do is take an arbitrarily large set of numbers, find the midrange, and divide that set into two smaller subsets. Kinda like a quicksort (which I have no idea how to implement by the way).

The reason I believe Ill need to be able to declare these datatypes after compilation is because I want to be able to create an arbitrary amount of subsets as well, based off user input.

So, for example if the user specifies 8 levels then the program should be able to divide the original set with the method described above, and repeat that with all the subsequent subsets. It appears, to me that in order to organize the numbers in this way would require the use of arrays, hence the problem I'm running into.

Is there a simpler way to approach this problem? If there is I'd really appreciate some insight. And if not, how can I do what I described above?

To clarify, I am writing this program in Java, and no, this is not a homework assignment.

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: First: which programming language is this in? Different language have very different typing and declaration contraints; and not all even require declarations per se...

Comment: Depends on the language in use.

Comment: Is this question about homework? If so, you could tag it as so, and provide your best shot at a solution to get prompt and relevant answers.

Comment: Nope, not about homework. Just trying to write a program I've been thinking of. And its in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a 2D array (which is an array of arrays).  This initial declaration might be:

```
int[][]  array;
```

When you know how many subarrays you'll need, you can create the array with one known dimension:

```
array = new int[8][];
```

You have now created an array that can hold 8 subarrays of type int[], but the subarrays don't yet exist.  To create one, you can do this:

```
array[0] = new int[15];
array[1] = new int[12];
// etc.
```

Note that each subarray can be of a different size if you want.

Comment: Oh. Ok, so that means that I could take user input assign it to a variable being the array size, then generate subsequent arrays as I need them?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm not sure why I didn't immediately think of doing this... Thanks again haha.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing a [recursive function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29).

Also, if you want something like an int[] but don't know the size at *initialization time*, an ArrayList will allow you to .add() any number of Integer objects.

Note that you said **compile time** and I said **initialization time**.  You don't need to hard code the length of an array at compile time.  It can be initialized with a variable like so:

```
int[] items = new int[x]();
```

Comment: Ah, yes, alright. Thanks for the help. I think the hard part now will be figuring out how to implement it. But good stuff. I'd up vote you if i could haha.

Answer (score 0):

I like using array but for creating sub sets or sub list using a list may be a better choice.

```
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i=0;i<128;i++) ints.add(i);

int subLists = 8;
int subListSize = (ints.size() + subLists - 1) / subLists;
List<List<Integer>> intsList = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
for(int i = 0; i < ints.size(); i += subListSize)
  intsList.add(ints.subList(i, Math.max(i+subListSize, ints.size())));
```

Comment: oh wow. I've been trying to implement it for the last few hours haha, this could be a far better solution. I'm gonna try and wrap my head around this, and tell you how it works out.

Comment: One thing I am not understanding is why you made the sublist size that value.....17 Oh and the last line is puzzling haha. What I'm seeing it that you are adding a sublist....?

Comment: Just to clarify, the list of numbers is a random one. And I am sorting it using a method similar to quick sort producing a binary tree of sorts. I may be mistaken but this method seems to rely on the numbers being sequential....right? heh. Or I could simply be wrong.

Comment: Lists rely on the numbers being ordered.  The sublists are a "view" on the original list so if you change the original, the sublists appear to change and visa-versa. Usually you would use a quick sort OR a binary tree to sort data. The numbers don't need to be sorted in fact bizarrely you can sort the numbers AFTER taking the sublists.